# How to resolve integer overflow?

Tags: r, matrix, integer-overflow

I have created a matrix (`matA`) of 1000 rows and 1000 columns, and I want to calculate powers of this matrix. It works very well up to calculating the third power of the matrix. But when I ask to calculate its fourth power, it gives a warning message saying,

> In matA * matA * matA * matA : NAs produced by integer overflow

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Convert the integer to numeric?

Comment: You want elemetwise power or matrix power as in t(mat)%*%mat?

Comment: Need the matrix power. I tried numeric conversion. but it gives the same warning.

Answer (score 4):

Since you didn't give an example:

```
set.seed(101)
z <- matrix(rnorm(1e6),1e3)
z2 <- round(z)*1000000
storage.mode(z2) <- "integer"
```

If you really want a matrix power (as in `z2 %*% z2 %*% z2 %*% z2`), it's best to use the `Matrix` or `expm` package.

```
library(expm)
z4C <- z2 %^% 4
```

On the other hand, if you really want the elementwise product

```
z4D <- z2*z2*z2*z2
## Warning message "NAs produced"
```

All you need to do is convert to numeric.

```
storage.mode(z2) <- "numeric"
z4E <- z2*z2*z2*z2  ## fine
```